# how can refrence a javascript file to UserControl in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, user-controls

how can use from a js file in usercontrol in asp.net

in webform put this line in head but in usercontol we have not head tag

```
<script src="../Scripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartUpScript` to set your scripts at the end of the page at server side. Or use ready event of the JQuery ensure the dom is loaded, and then bind your client side events to your link.

`RegisterStartupScript`, registers your scripts at the end of the page, so your script loaded after all the elements of the page loaded.

One other option is to use ready event of the JQuery, it helps you to wait all elements of DOM loaded. You can implement your ready function at inline or server side.

The key point here is to wait for the DOM elements load.

Comment: This links will also help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703601/where-do-i-put-javascript-when-using-an-asp-net-user-control

Comment: may you give me a sample